# how to change the background image of div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my code

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div class="ghor" id="a" onclick="chek_mark()"></div>
  function call
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function chek_mark(){
   var el= document.getElementById("a").style.background-image;
   if (el.url("Black-Wallpaper.jpg"))  
   {
     el.url = "cross1.png";
    }
    else if(el.url("cross1.png"))
    {
      alert("<h1>This is working too.</h1>");
     }
   }
</script>
```

here I want to change the background image using if else condition

```
this is the style-sheet
.ghor //this is the div class
{
    background-image: url('Black-Wallpaper.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 7px 7px white;
    /*background-color: black;*/
    display:inline-block; 
}
```

i want change the background image of the 'div' which class is 'ghor'

Comment: how can this line `var el= document.getElementById("a").style.background-image;` work? There's a minus sign in a property... I should have thought it would have to be `var el= document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundImage;`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('a').style.backgroundImage="url(images/img.jpg)"; // specify the image path here
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: any chance to manipulate referere here?

Answer (score 5):

try this one!

```
var el = document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundImage;
if(el == "url(Black-Wallpaper.jpg)") { // full value is provided
   el.style.backgroundImage = "url(/link/to_new_file.png)"; // change it
}
```

Comment: Will this only get the filename, or will it also get the path?

Comment: @Avisari, it will get the value of the `background-image` css property. If file path is provided, its value will include file path too. Otherwise only the image!

Comment: '(/link/to_new_file.png)' what should i write here

Comment: it's not working 'var el = document.getElementById('a').backgroundImage;
    if (el == "url(Black-Wallpaper.jpg)") 
      {
     //el.style.backgroundImage = "url(cross1.png)"; 
     alert("its working");
    }'

Comment: Please add `('a').style.backgrounImage` instead of simple `('a').backgroundImage`. Because background is a property of style of the object not a property of the object.

Comment: @Afzaal, yeah that's what I thought. Usually the path is also provided, which means that he will either have to do the full path check `el == "url(path/image.format)"` or split it to only get the filename to compare against.

Comment: @Avisari, yes, I have now updated my answer on a check. Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in following ways

**STEP 1**

```
   var imageUrl= "URL OF THE IMAGE HERE";
   var BackgroundColor="RED"; // what ever color you want
```

For changing background of **BODY**

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage=imageUrl  //changing bg image
document.body.style.backgroundColor=BackgroundColor //changing bg color
```

**To change an element with ID**

```
document.getElementById("ElementId").style.backgroundImage=imageUrl
document.getElementById("ElementId").style.backgroundColor=BackgroundColor
```

**for elements with same class**

```
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].style.background=imageUrl;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

### **HTML**

```
<body id="body">
</body>
```

### **JavaScript**

you can set the time also.

```
//Initializing
var i = 0;
var images = []; //array
var time = 3000; // time in millie seconds

//images

images[0] = "url(./Images/1.jpg)";
images[1] = "url(./Images/2.jpg)";
images[2] = "url(./Images/3.jpg)";
//function

function changeImage() {
    var el = document.getElementById('body');
    el.style.backgroundImage = images[i];
    if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout('changeImage()', time);
}

window.onload = changeImage;
```

### **CSS**

```
overflow-x: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on why this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```js
    

 //Here is an example how to change background image of <div> element using javascript  by feching a new URL form some API.
 // let image teched from API: this is the image you want to put as new background !
// thumbnail image:
// data.picture.thumbnail
//the HTML element whose background needs to be changes is given an id of #thumbnail.

 var thumbUrl = document.querySelector("#thumbnail");
     
//using a function which will update data in the HTML - this is done
//after parsing of the data fetched, I have omitted the steps used for parsing the data.
function updateData(data){
   //data.picture.medium represents our new fetched data containing the URL fo the new image we want to use as background image.
    var newImage=data.picture.medium;
    thumbUrl.style.backgroundImage="url("+newImage+")";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Get the Element from the DOM
var element = document.getElementById("a");

// Change the background image
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('Black-Wallpaper.jpg')"
```

Answer (score 0):

//Here is an example how to change background image of  element using javascript  by feching a new URL form some API.

// let image teched from API: this is the image you want to put as new background !

// thumbnail image:

// data.picture.thumbnail

//the HTML element whose background needs to be changes is given an id of #thumbnail.

```
var thumbUrl = document.querySelector("#thumbnail");
```

//using a function which will update data in the HTML - this is done

//after parsing of the data fetched, I have omitted the steps used for parsing the data.

```
function updateData(data){

  //data.picture.medium represents our new fetched data containing the URL fo the new image we want to use as background image.
  var newImage=data.picture.medium;
  thumbUrl.style.backgroundImage="url("+newImage+")";

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can do this

backgroundImage: `url(${musics[0].image})`

Answer (score -2):

Bro same problem occured with me.
Then I realised that javascript does not work properly when the element's position is fixed or absolute.try changingits position to relative or just remove position property.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32400988)