# Change a div background image using javascript if/else

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the background image of a div to change at an interval. I created an Array with the images, and every few seconds the function should check the value of "x" against the array length. If X is less, x will increase by one and the background image will change to the next image in the array, otherwise it will set x=0 and restart the process.
The div and initial image shows up how I want, but nothing happens.

I know there are probably better ways to do this, but I am very new to Javascript and want to learn why this code doesn't work. Thanks in advance for the help!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

       <title>ImageChanger</title>

       <style type="text/css">

       #imagediv {
            float:left;
            border-style:ridge;
            border-width:8px;
            border-color:Green;
            border-radius:15px;
            width:1250px;
            height:450px;
            background-image:url(images/landscape1.jpg)
        }

       </style>

       <script type="text/javascript">

            function  displayNextImage() {
            var x;

            If (x<imageArray.length) {
                x=x+1;
                document.getElementById("imagediv").style.backgroundImage=images[x];
            } 
            else {
                x=0;
                document.getElementById("imagediv").style.backgroundImage=images[x];
            }

            function startTimer() {
                  setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
            }

            var imageArray=new Array();
            images[0] = "images/landscape1.jpg";
            images[1] = "images/landscape2.jpg";
            images[2] = "images/landscape3.jpg";
            images[3] = "images/landscape4.jpg";

       </script>
   </head>

    <body>
       <div id="imagediv">
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the background image of div using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496905/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Learn to use the JavaScript console in the browser. It will point you in the general area of the bugs. Missing a closing } and have a typo on the if.

Comment: code is missing some brace `fix ` it

Answer (score 2):

```
  If (x<imageArray.length) {..
```

should be

```
 if (x<imageArray.length) {
```

Javascript is *[case-sensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp).*

Also you have some missing `braces` like you are not closing

```
function  displayNextImage() { ....
```

Use your browser console to debug. These syntax errors will be shown there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as syntax issues go:

1. As @Zee stated, `If` should be lowercase (`if`)
2. Also, as @Zee and some others stated, you are not closing `function displayNextImage() {` with a closing brace `}`.
3. You are improperly defining the `background-image` property in your function, whereas you defined it correctly in the block of CSS.  You must wrap the image name with `url()`.
4. You are never calling your timeout function, `startTimer`.
5. You create a new array `imageArray` but then use an undeclared array `images`