# Add background image to a div via javascript

Tags: javascript, background-image

```
<div class="splash-image-wrap splash-image">
<img class="splash-image-bg" src="http://mysite-com/image.jpg" alt="image-bg">
</div>
```

Can you help me with a script that adds the img src url as image background for the wrap div?

I'm trying this but does not work

```
$(function () {

function updatePageForTopImg(){
    // background image using size cover
    // top background image
    $('.splash-image-wrap').css('background-image', 'url('+$(".splash-image-bg").attr("src")+')').css('background-size' , 'cover').css('background-position' , 'top center');
}
$(window).on('load', function(){
updatePageForTopImg();
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the background image of div using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496905/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-div-using-javascript)

Comment: How about doing it in plain CSS? As I can see in your Code you have the src of the image already aviable. If you want to be abble to toggle the background on or off you should implement CSS rules representing the both toggle status. Applying huge chunks of CSS via JS is a bad practise.

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep things that are static in your css file, such as background-size and background-position.

JS:

```
$('.splash-image-wrap').css({
    background-image: 'url(" + $('.splash-image-bg').attr('src') + ")'
});
```

CSS:

```
.splash-image-bg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Also as a sidenote, you do not need `window.load` or `document.ready` in your code after you have wrapped it like `$(function(){})`.

`window.load` is used for waiting for inner frames and images to load. Since you haven't injected your background image yet, you do not need to wait for this to run your code.

Also, `document.ready` is equivalent to wrapping your function like `$(function() {`, which you are already doing. You can completely scrap these and have it still work.

Comment: Exact answer! Deleted my post ;) Did not realized the `$` in front of the `(function() {})` +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're loading the jQuery library, the following should work:

```
$('.splash-image-wrap').css({
    'background-image': 'url(" + $('.splash-image-bg').attr('src') + ")',
    'background-size': 'cover',
    'background-position': 'top center'
});
```

If not, you'd need to rewrite your function using vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct code, however not sure why you have a `$(window).load`.
Here is a working version

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/rn7ejrke/1/

jQuery

```
function updatePageForTopImg() {
        // background image using size cover
        // top background image
        $('.splash-image-wrap')
            .css('background-image', 'url(' + $(".splash-image-bg").attr("src") + ')')
            .css('background-size', 'cover')
            .css('background-position', 'top center');
    }

$(function () {
    updatePageForTopImg();
});
```