# change background image when input value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm looking for a script, wich changes the background image of an div container when spefic numbers are into the input field.

I build this creditcard layout here

[image: credit card]

inside of it is a `<input type="text" name="" class="credit-input">` with the class `credit-input`.

What i'm looking for is, that if the first three numbers inside the value generate a different background.

So for example, when the value starts with 411, there should be a background image of an amex card, or when it starts with 311, there should be mastercards and so on.

there would be in total 4 different backgrounds.

i'm not so good in js, so i hope that i could find here some help from ya.

That's how my `html` looks at the moment.The `class="jp-front"` includes the whole style at the moment the

```
<div class="jp-front">
                <input type="text" name="" class="credit-input">
            </div>
```

thx for any help

Comment: So, what you tired so far? show the `JS` code please

Comment: You can use onchange onkeypress onkeydown js events to get each time value of input and check first 4 symbols.

Comment: unfortunately i do not have any js code, cause i'm not so good into it. If i'm wrong here with that, i would delete the post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496905/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-div-using-javascript here is how to change background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".credit-input").on("input",function(){

        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == "411") 
            $(".jp-front").css({backgroundImage:"url(http://www.lowestrates.ca/newcontent/img/creditcards/Gold_Rewards_Card_chip_467x293.png)"});

        else if (value == "311")
            $(".jp-front").css({backgroundImage:"url(https://www.bmo.com/img/main/credit-cards/large/rewards-card.jpg)"});

    })

})
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".credit-input").on("input",function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    if (value == "411") 
      $(".jp-front").css({backgroundImage:"url(http://www.lowestrates.ca/newcontent/img/creditcards/Gold_Rewards_Card_chip_467x293.png)"});
    
    else if (value == "311")
      $(".jp-front").css({backgroundImage:"url(https://www.bmo.com/img/main/credit-cards/large/rewards-card.jpg)"});
            
        })
                
    })
```

```css
.jp-front {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jp-front">
  <input type="text" name="" class="credit-input">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Made my day.


Thank you so much ehsan. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your input element will be -

```
<div class="jp-front">
    <input type="text" name="card-number" class="credit-input">
</div>
```

Let your image element be

```
<img src="default.jpg" id="card-img">
```

Your JavaScript will be like this -

```
$('input[name=card-number]').keyup(function() {

    var inp = $('input[name=search]').val();
    if (inp === '311') {
        $("#card-img").attr("src","mastercards.jpg");
    }
    else if (inp === '411') {
        $("#card-img").attr("src","amex.jpg");
    }
    else if (inp === '') {
        $("#card-img").attr("src","default.jpg");
    }
});
```

Thank You!

Comment: hey thx, for the code. looks greate but its not working for me. it only change for example when i type 411 but not by the other ones

Comment: Hi @PeymanEtedali! Please try now, I have edited the code a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not overly complex, but this should do the trick:

```
$("input[name='card']").keyup( function() {

    img = 'blank.png';

    switch($(this).val().substring(0, 3)) {

    case '111':
      img = '111.png';
      break;
    case '222':
      img = '222.png';
      break;
    }

    $('.img').css('background', 'url(' + img + ') no-repeat center center');
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6hhtgnep/

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't JQuery

Add id="..." and onchange="" onkeypress="" onkeydown=""

```
<div class="jp-front" id="card-div-id">
    <input id="card-input-field-id" type="text" name="" onchange="onCodeInput()" onkeypress="onCodeInput()" onkeydown="onCodeInput()" class="credit-input">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function onCodeInput(){
       var card_number = document.getElementById('card-input-field-id').value;
       if (str.substr(0, 4) == '5466') {
           document.getElementById('card-div-id').style.backgroundImage="url(images/mastercard.jpg)"
       } else { /* others */ }
    }
</script>
```