# Replace a style value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I am looking to change a value in a tag with js.

```
<div class="class1" style="background-image:url(https://www.awebsite.com/sites/default/files/a_image.jpg?t=1529620960)"></div>
```

I want to change this :

```
https://www.awebsite.com/sites/default/files/a_image.jpg?t=1529620960`
```

to this:

```
https://hello.com/an-other-image.jpg
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your question seems unclear.On what action do you want to replace ? Is it on click of button or something?

Comment: and your attempt is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the background image of div using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496905/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-div-using-javascript)

Comment: document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Firstly, sorry for my bad english, It's hard to fully explain what i want to do. I've test somes codes, tried to edit thems but i'm very bad in JS, it was only for a userscript. Thanks for your answers and sorry for being so unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get a reference to the `<div>` element and then update it's [style attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

```
// querySelector can use CSS selectors to find the element in the document
// note: this is assuming there is only 1 element on page with this class
var myDiv = document.querySelector('.class1');
// Style properties generally match CSS but camel cased
myDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://hello.com/an-other-image.jpg")';
```

You may want to consider adding an `id` in which case you can use an ID selector or [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

If there are *multiple elements* you want to update, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which will return an array of matches which you can loop over and change.

```
function changeToAnotherBgImage(element) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://hello.com/an-other-image.jpg")';
}
// Plenty of alternate ways of writing, arrow function may be appropriate
document.querySelectorAll('.class1').forEach(changeToAnotherBgImage);
```

Comment: What if the class is applied to multiple elements? Not that the OP thought about that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Added a note about `querySelectorAll` - good calloout :)

Comment: It works well ! Thank you for taking the time to help me, I really learned something. I think I will take JS lessons, I did not think we could do this type of things (querySelector and  the .style.backgroundImage)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
c = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
for(i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    c[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://hello.com/an-other-image.jpg)';
}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. I just tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: This _works_ but is missing `var` or `let` for variable declarations. `forEach` is also widely supported and removes the tedium of an index variable. Really `el.style.backgroundImage` is the core part anyway, but just fyis that may be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

const eleDiv =document.querySelector('.class').style.background = "url('your imge') no-repeat";