# How can I set an image as an td background?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set each td as a different image that I have saved as imgn.gif. (n being image number, I have 13 images, img1.gif., img2.gif... img13.gif)  I have a code that generates the table now I just can't figure out how to set a background image, preferably so that the n imgn.gif changes to the next index so the next td will have the next image.

this is the code that I have for now. I assume I have to set something differently here: const cellText = document.createTextNode(2);, so it sets background-image instead?

```
function options ()
{
    const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

 
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      const cellText = document.createTextNode(2);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Comment: cell.setAttribute("src","images/cross.png") can use DOM setAttribute function for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the background image of div using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496905/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman `<td>` does not have `src` attribute, it's not image

Comment: my bad use this cell.style.backgroundImage =
"url('https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/geeksforgeeks-logo.png')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add 5 lines in you actual code:

```js
options();

    function options() {
        const tbl = document.createElement("table");
        const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        const nbImage = 13;
        let curImage = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                const cell = document.createElement("td");
                if (curImage > nbImage) {
                    curImage = 1;
                }
                cell.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img' + curImage + '.gif)';
                const cellText = document.createTextNode(2);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                curImage += 1;
            }
            tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        document.body.appendChild(tbl);

    }
```

I've added:

- nbImage (13 from your post)
- curImage to iterate through your 13 images

After your cell creation, checking the image number:

```
if (curImage > nbImage) {
   curImage = 1;
}
```

So your fourteenth TD will have the image 1

Your is already created as a DOM element so you can refer it and add a background image:

```
cell.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img' + curImage + '.gif)';
```

That will add for each TD a backgound image "img1.gif", "img2.gif"... till "img13.gif", after "img1.gif" ... and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable (nImage for exemple) starting from 1 to 13 and reset it when up to 13 so it came back to 1. Then use this variable to modify `style.backgroundImage` of your td :

```
function options ()
{
    const tbl = document.createElement("table");
    const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    let nImage = 1 ;

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        const row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            const cell = document.createElement("td");
            const cellText = document.createTextNode(2);

            if (nImage > 13){nImage =1 ;}
            cell.style.backgroundImage = "url('yourPathTo/img"+nImage + ".gif')" ;
            nImage++ ;

            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```