# html -Making an image the background image on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I don't have any code for this because I am fully stuck and unsure where to begin. The concept is simple enough - I want to be able to click an image (from several others on the page) and have it become the background image for the page.

I am aware I'll need JavaScript to do this, but I don't know where to start.

I was going to specify an array to select from in JavaScript, but then I wasn't sure how to specify that the input of the specific image being clicked would change the background image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the background image of div using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496905/how-to-change-the-background-image-of-div-using-javascript)

Comment: `<div onClick="changeBackground($indexOfArrayElement)">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create click handlers for your `img` elements which will set the proper `style` attributes of `document.body`:

```js
for (let img of document.querySelectorAll("img")) {
    img.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${this.src}')`;
        document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
    })
}
```

```html
<img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.wwxK07x0Umfnh0l-nrjxjgHaDg?pid=ImgDet&rs=1">
<img src="https://www.forestis.it/media/1064/forestis-see-idm.jpg?mode=max&rnd=132197836980000000">
```